# TextView with scrollbar - Python 3 Glade Gtk +3

Tags: python, gtk3, glade

Well, I can not put a scroll bar in the text view. I went through all sorts of documentation available to solve my problem, but I did not find anything to help me. Every time the text exceeds the text display the window increases, according to the text display. So I'm trying to put a scroll bar in the text view so that it does not happen, but I can not. Please help me!

Project link.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=15NeiNO7-LRq_L6E0AqNMtK0_iNmFswRr

[Class Handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9GUt.png)
[Gtk.Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqmiJ.png)

Comment: Please paste your code into your question instead of sharing a google drive document.

Comment: The code is an extensive one. So I decided to put the link on google drive. And I also could not put the scrollbar in the text view, so I'm asking you for help. I'm a beginner in this library.

Comment: In that case, please paste only the relevant code. Currently, your docs link shows the *entire* project. Nobody wants to search through that to find the problem.

Comment: Okay so I'll just add the python code, which I think is where I can not put the scroll bar in the text view.

Comment: The problem is in your Glade file, not Python code. There is no scrollbar at all. First you need to add a `GtkScolledWindow` in a container (`caixa2` for you) and in there add a `GtkTextView`, not the other way around.